# Django - How to pass queryset to the template using a class based UpdateView?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to pass a **queryset** into the **fields collection** (shown in the views.py)? My intend is to **populate a select HTML element** with only active members. Or is there any other way or best practice to solve this?

**views.py:**

```
class Orders_update(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    active_members = Member.objects.all().filter(active=True)
    fields = ['order_text', 'customer', 'active_members']
    template_name = "orders/orders_update.html"
    success_url = '../../../orders'
```

**orders_update.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Order - Update</h1>
<form class="form-group" style="width:200px" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.order_text|add_class:"form-control" }}
        {{ form.customer|add_class:"form-control" }}
        {{ form.active_members|add_class:"form-control" }}
        <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Update" />
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member')
    order_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pick_up = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    changed_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def created(self):
        self.changed_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_text


class Customer(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    changed_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def created(self):
        self.changed_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self): return self.company_name


class Member(models.Model):
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    changed_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def created(self):
        self.changed_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname
```

Comment: Please show your models.

Comment: Just updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to restrict options for the `Order.members` field to those with `active=True`.

You can do this by creating a model form, and changing the queryset in the `__init__` method.

```
from django import forms

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['order_text', 'customer', 'members']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['members'].queryset = Member.objects.all().filter(active=True)
```

Then update your view to use your model form by setting [`form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class).

```
class Orders_update(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm
    ...
```

Finally, the field is call member, so you should change the template to:

```
{{ form.member|add_class:"form-control" }}
```

As an aside, it's not recommended to use a relative url like `'../../../orders'`. It would be better to use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy). For example, if the name of the URL pattern is `orders`, then you can use:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('orders')
```

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot! But in the Order form I had to add `model = Member` after `class Meta:` and in the `__init__` it needs to be `self.fields['members'].queryset`. With this I was getting the desired result. If you update your answer, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I've fixed the line that sets the queryset. I thought that you didn't need to set `model` in the form, since you are doing it in the view, but I might have remembered incorrectly. However, if you do set the model, it should be `Order`, not `Member`.